# TF Keras Model Serving REST API JSON Input Format

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

So I tried following [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/keras) and deploy the model using docker tensorflow serving image. Let's say there are 4 features: feat1, feat2, feat3 and feat4. I tried to hit the prediction endpoint {url}/predict with this JSON body:

```
{
"instances": 
[
    {
        "feat1": 26,
        "feat2": 16, 
        "feat3": 20.2, 
        "feat4": 48.8
    }
]}
```

I got 400 response code:

```
{
"error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: feat1 of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: feat"
}
```

This is the signature passed to model.save():

```
signatures = {
      'serving_default':
          _get_serve_tf_examples_fn(model,
                                    tf_transform_output).get_concrete_function(
                                        tf.TensorSpec(
                                            shape=[None],
                                            dtype=tf.string,
                                            name='examples')),
  }
```

I understand that from this signature that in every instances element, the only field being accepted is "examples" but when I tried to only pass this one only with empty string:

```
{
    "instances": 
    [
        {
            "examples": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I also got bad request: `{"error": "Name: <unknown>, Feature: feat1 (data type: int64) is required but could not be found.\n\t [[{{node ParseExample/ParseExampleV2}}]]"}`

I couldn't find in the guide how to build the JSON body request the right way, it would be really helpful if anyone can point this out or give references regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this problem by changing the signature serving input but it raised another exception. This problem already solved, check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530885/tfx-pipeline-error-while-executing-tfma-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-n/64601850#64601850).

Answer (score 1):

In that example, the serving function expects a serialized `tf.train.Example` proto as input. This [page](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict?hl=en_US#binary_data_in_prediction_input) explains how binary data can be passed to a deployed model as a string (explaining why the signature expects a tensor of strings). So what you need to do is build an Example proto containing your features and send that over. It could look something like this:

```py
import base64
import tensorflow was tf

features = {'feat1': 26,, 'feat2': 16, "feat3": 20.2, "feat4": 48.8}

# Create an Example proto from your feature dict.
feature_spec = {
  k: tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[float(v)]))
  for k, v in features.items()
}
example = tf.train.Example(
  features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_spec)).SerializeToString()

# Encode your serialized Example using base64 so it can be added into your
# JSON payload.
b64_example = base64.b64encode(example).decode()
result = [{'examples': {'b64': b64_example}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/model --all`? You should follow the output to serialize your request.

Comment: signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['examples'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_examples:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['output_0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

Comment: as I said on the question section it only receive one named field 'example' with type string. I suspected that this field is meant for serialized example instance. I already found solution with this problem by modifying _get_serve_tf_examples_fn function. I will share my solution later